# A genral Turing model with one tape to define sublinear space (L,NL,..)

Tags: turing-machines, time-complexity, space-complexity, definitions

A genral Turing model with one tape to define sublinear space (L,NL,..)

Normally to define sub-linear space complexity we need special Turing models with many tapes, at least two: a read-only tape and a work tape; or often three: with an additional output tape. (We do this because the reading of the input would cost us linear space.)

I'm looking for a *general* Turing model with just one tape and one consistent definition for space and for complexity that works in all the cases, inclusively the sub-linear case of L (Logspace), NL (NLogspace).. and the more famous P, NP, PSPACE etc.

For this purpose obviously we must change the space definition - but how best?

EDIT: For example: if we just count the new written cells in a one-tape machine would this solve the problem?

Comment: *Why* are you looking for such a model?

Comment: It would be more practical if one general uniform definition is used.

Comment: The "work tape" definition can be used for all complexity classes you mention. It is the general uniform definition you're after

Comment: Since you are shooting for "practical", it's more practical to have working tapes.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I know this definition works in all cases but I would prefer a simpler model with just one tape. I've added a special case in the "EDIT".